# PDO fetchAll not returning all rows

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, fetch, fetchall

So I am trying to get multiple things from database. It is not working.
    In my functions file I have:

```
public function getAllMultiple($username, $course) {
        foreach ($course as $key) {
        $query = $this->database->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE `posted_by` = ? OR `shared` = ? ORDER BY `date_added` DESC");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $key['1']);
        try {
            $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
}
```

In my feed function I have:

```
$array = $course->getAllAsMember($username);
print_r($course->getAllMultiple($username, $array);
```

I have two courses. I have a **drug** course and a **class** course. Unfortunately, it is only returning the **drug** course. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You replace the value of `$query` with each iteration, and never execute it.  I'm surprised its working at all.  If the above isn't your actual code, then please update it.

Comment: You need to provide more code, there is no `fetchAll` and you are not returning anything from your function here. You should also prepare your query before the loop as you only need to do that once.

Comment: Just updated it @jeroen

Comment: Your function is failing because the moment it returns, it stops execution of the function and never gets to the second array item.

Comment: My bad for not providing all the code.

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to collect all your results in an array and return that at the very end of your function.

Comment: I have tried it has not been working. I did `return array($query->fetchAll());`

Comment: @user1475632 That won't work either, for the simple reason as it's nowhere near the same.. all you're doing is returning an array you created within the loop.. meaning it doesn't add a value to an existing array.

Comment: OK I got your new answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you can do something like:

```
public function getAllMultiple($username, $course) {
    $query = $this->database->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE `posted_by` = ? OR `shared` = ? ORDER BY `date_added` DESC");
    $results = array();
    foreach ($course as $key) {

        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $key['1']);
        try {
            $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        results[] = $query->fetchAll();
     }
    return $results;
}
```

You should also improve your error handling, for example by putting everything within a `try` - `catch` block instead of just a part of it.

Comment: Would be way better to use IN() or a JOIN instead of running queries over and over again.

Comment: @Jessica Yes, making only one query is best and should be no problem here; this is just to address the current problem the OP is having, I have not really looked at the sql.

Comment: @user1475632 You should take Jessica's suggestion to reduce the number of queries to 1 regardless of the number of results.

Comment: @Jessica I would use that but have no clue. Sorry, I'm only 13 years old and am pretty new to php

Comment: I understand. I just took your advice and learned about join. Really cool stuff. Thanks @Jessica

Answer (score 1):

The return bit of your function stops execution of the function and returns the value.  If you want to return both results of the queries you execute, you need to assign them to an array, and then return that:

```
public function getAllMultiple($username, $course) {
    $return = array(); //initialize the array before the foreach function
    foreach ($course as $key) {
        $query = $this->database->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE `posted_by` = ? OR `shared` = ? ORDER BY `date_added` DESC");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $key['1']);
        try {
            $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        $return[] = $query->fetchAll(); //collect the results
    }
    return $return; //return the array
}
```

Hopefully my comments are self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you a bunch. That will save me lots of time.

Comment: Un-accept my answer.  I was beaten to the punch by a better answer, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830526/785241